# Big-O notation confusion

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, calculus

I have come across some of the difficulties during doing this question. The question is: sort the following functions by order of growth from slowest to fastest:

```
7n^3 − 10n, 4n^2, n, n^8621909, 3n, 2^(log log n), n log n, 6n log n, n!, 1.1^n
```

And my answer to the question is

1. n,3n
2. nlogn, 6nlogn
3. 4n^2(which equals to n^2)
4. 7n^3 – 10n(which equals to n^3)
5. n^ 8621909
6. 2^loglogn
7. 1.1^n(exponent 2^0.1376n)
8. n!

Just wondering: can I assume that `2^(loglogn)` has the same growth as `2^n`? Should I take `1.1^n` as a constant?

Comment: A bit off-topic but ... if had investment giving you 10% annually, for sure you would notice how `1.1^n` is different  from a constant! In 7.27 years you would have doubled your initial investment!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Just wondering can i assume that 2^(loglogn) has the same growth as
>   2^n?

No. Assuming that the logs are in base 2 then `2^log(n)` mathematically equals to `n`, so `2^(log(log(n)) = log(n)`. And of course it does not have the same growth as `2^n`.

> Should I take 1.1^n as a constant?

No. `1.1^n` is still an exponent by `n` that cannot be ignored - of course it is not a constant.

The correct order is:

```
2^loglogn = log(n)
n,3n
nlogn, 6nlogn
4n^2
7n^3 – 10n
n^8621909
1.1^n
n!
```

I suggest to take a look at the [Formal definition of the Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). But, for simplicity, the top of the list goes slower to infinity than the lower functions.
If for example, you will put two of those function on a graph you will see that one function will eventually pass the other one and will go faster to infinity.

Take a look at [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5E2+and+2%5En) comparing `n^2` with `2^n`. You will notice that `2^n` is passing `n^2` and going faster to infinity.
You might also want to check the graph in [this page](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

Comment: I think the final three in your series could use an explanation (i.e. why `n^8621909`, `1.1^n`, and `n!` appear in this order).

Comment: "2^log(x) mathematically equals `n`".  No.  `2^(log base 2 of x)` is equal to `n`.  However, `O(2^log(x)) = x`

Comment: @intboolstring thanks for this correction to make it precise. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

1. *2<sup>log(x)</sup> = x*, so *2<sup>log(log(n))</sup> = log(n)*, which grows *far* more slower than *2<sup>n</sup>*.
2. *1.1<sup>n</sup>* is definitely not a constant. *1.1<sup>n</sup>* tends to infinity, and a constant obviously does not.

Comment: The OP needs to order the functions from slowest to fastest growing.  Can you do this?